# how to use pop in angularjs with material design?

Tags: angularjs

i recently started using the latest Google Material Design Lite,I have tried to include model popup  into it, but that's not working infect seems pretty messed

Any Idea what will work good as an replacement ??

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org

Comment: Have you ever tried md-dialog?

Comment: Try https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog